# returning true in onTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent not working correct

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm implementing an `ImageView` that can handle touch events and using it inside a `ViewPager`. In my `ImageView`s `onTouchEvent` and `dispatchTouchEvent` for testing I'm always returning true but it's not working correct and `ViewPager` is still working when I'm sliding on my `ImageView`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't looking at the full touch chain.  ViewPager implements onInterceptTouchEvent, which gets a chance to take touch events away from a child view.  Look into requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent on the ViewPager, and read up on the full touch handling chain at https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: so i need to implement a view pager which not responds to touches when my image view will handle it?

Comment: No, you need to call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvents when the image view is first touched, then call it again to re-enable it when the touch is done.